# What is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ isomorphic to - Fraleigh p. 112 Exercises 11.32e

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

**(e).** p. 4 of [PDF](http://acunix.wheatonma.edu/jsklensk/Abstract_Fall10/classwork/october/oct13-inclass.pdf) - $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 \not\simeq \mathbb{Z}_8$. [Another solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/550135.)

(1.) Why is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ not cyclic? Is it because of $ \gcd(2, 4) = 2 \neq 1 \iff$ p. 106 Corollary 11.6?
[image]

Reference: p. 11 of the same PDF. robjohn nicely the version with no colors under.
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN1ud.png).

[image]

> **Alternative Approach to showing $f$ is onto:**
>   Define $f:\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$ by $f(m)=(m\mod2,m\mod3)$.
>
> $2$ and $3$ relatively prime $\implies\exists s,t$ such that $1=2s+3t$. In fact, $1=2(-1)+3(1)$.
>   Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$. Need to find a $g\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $f(g)=(a,b)$.
>
> Define $\color{magenta}{g=3ta+2sb}$. That is, define $g=3(1)a-2(-1)b=3a-2b$. NTS $f(g)=(a,b)$.

(2.) Where does this $\color{magenta}{g=3ta+2sb}$ spring from magically? Can someone please unfold it?

Comment: Please use `\mathbb` correctly (i.e., only on the specific capital letters you want it to apply to, not an entire expression.)

Answer (score 0):

Corollary 11.6 you describe exactly tells you that $\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_4$ is not cyclic, so your reasoning is correct. Another way of proving that is simple.

Take any element $a\oplus b \in\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_4$ Now it's easy to show that $$(a\oplus b)+(a\oplus b)+(a\oplus b)+(a\oplus b) = 0,$$ meaning all elements of the group have order at most $4$.
Since $1\in\mathbb Z_8$ has order $8$, the groups are not isomorphic.

For the second question, the simplest way to answer is that picking that $g$ simply *works*. More completely thought, the idea is not that hard.

You want to find such a $g$ that $$g\equiv a \mod 2$$ and $$g\equiv b \mod 3.$$

Setting $g=3a+2b$ makes sure both equations hold.

Comment: Thanks. But the answer has s and t for its $\color{magenta}{g=3ta+2sb}$. Can you please unfold why yours doesn't?